# How to use nvm to upgrade Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

Now I use Node.js in version 0.10.21, how to upgrade to v0.10.23 with out reinstall the whole Node.js and global NPM packages.

Answer (score 1):

you can try following command which provided from nvm

```
nvm copy-packages <version> //Install global NPM packages contained in <version> to current version
```

Comment: I know this, but I don't want to use this way, I thought it would have  a more easy method, install the new version, trans the npm to current version automatic, even without uninstall the old one

Answer (score 0):

Use Node Version Manager to keep old Node versions and installing newer versions: https://github.com/creationix/nvm#node-version-manager-
Then just follow the README to install other Node and npm versions...